# After installing Cadence and Jack I have to start the client each time to listen to audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack, daw

I installed Jack and Cadence in order to record audio and to link the PulseAudio to the Jack.

Everything works fine with my DAW. But now I face a new problem.

If I don't want to use my DAW but just want to listen to Spotify or Youtube audio, I nevertheless have to start Cadence and PulseAudio/Jack Bridge in order to get an audio signal out of the speakers.

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you see drop-down menu in 'pavucontrol --tab 1' to switch playback from 'Pulseaudio JACK Sink' to an ALSA output device ?

Comment: hallo. i installed pavucontrol. and there are five tabs ('wiedergabe', 'aufnahme', 'ausgabegerät', 'eingabegerät', 'konfiguration'). in english this would be something like 'playback', 'recording', 'output device', 'input device', 'configuration'. i looked into the first and third tab and there is no drop-down menu. there is just a label with the caption 'Jack sink (PulseAudio Jack Sink)'. below this there is a line where you can set the volume of the device. it is set to 100% (0 dB).

Comment: additional option '--tab 1' was to go direct to first tab 'weidergabe'
if the bit marked

Comment: https://www.linux-community.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Abbildung-3-4.jpg